# DIV element with box-shadow appearing behind DIV element with image

Tags: html, css

I have tried for hours now -- so desperate attempt to consult this community now.

I have a website I am developing and I have a div element with a box-shadow at the bottom and then an image in a span tag next to it.

The box-shadow keeps appearing behind the image. I have tried pseduo elements, position variables, etc with css but nothing works.

How can I bring the shadow infront of the image?

A pure css solution would be great.

[image: css]

Page can be found here: 
https://paradigmtek.com/tv-wall-mount-installation-2/

Comment: Can you include your code of that section of whatever you have or have tried, including the HTML and CSS code. It's hard to tell just from a screenshot alone, it could be caused by a million things

Comment: @Mark Ya that's why I included the page I am working on and hoping someone can go into dev tools and figure it out? It's a wordpress theme Avada so everything is so nested it would be hard to know what the relevant code is.

Comment: From messing around with it, the answer is no, you cannot put the shadow in front of the image. The shadow belongs to a big div, and shadows (and others such as borders) cannot be positioned on top of main elements. If I understand your question, you simply want to bring it forward, which is not possible.

Comment: Ya, I want to bring the shadow over the image -- really not possible?! no way...

Comment: I'm perplexed by all the replies saying this is not possible.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58532825/div-element-with-box-shadow-appearing-behind-div-element-with-image/58532975#58532975) below-- unless I am misunderstanding the question, just add `z-index` to bring the container to the forefront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your page, this is easily solved by giving the nav container (`.fusion-fullwidth.fullwidth-box.fusion-builder-row-1.title_heading_container_cust.hundred-percent-fullwidth.non-hundred-percent-height-scrolling`) a `z-index` of `100`.  It is the first child of the `.post-content`-classed div.

Comment: You're so money! THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem :) Glad this worked for you!  Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

As per your question, to bring forward a shadow is not possible (or I don't know a good way to do it).

A similar alternative is adding a `margin` to the image, to push it lower down the page.
The simplest fix is to go into the HTML file, and add inline CSS of `style="margin-top: x"`, or `style="margin: x 0 0 0"` where x is your desired value.

That would give a result very similar to the screenshot below.

[image]

plus, it doesn't look bad this way either :)

Comment: Ya I purposely removed the margin-top as I really wanted to have the shadow flow over the image. The design is not done and having a margin there won't be that great.